# How to continuously run your main code and also listen for new data and include it in your main code without blocking the main Thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. A simpler version of the code is shown below. I want to run a while loop that listens for new transactions via sockets and uses them in my while loop.

The issue is that if I don't leave the call stack, I'll never be able to add anything from the callback queue to the call stack. I tried using **setInterval(()=>/code here,0)**, but that didn't help unless I added a 10-20 second time interval. Code in the while loop is CPU intensive. For e.g. if while loop takes 60 seconds to complete, setInterval will add a large number of callbacks in the callback queue which means those sockets messages are there somewhere in the callback queue but I will get them after a long period of time because first, it will run all the callbacks added by setInterval and this continuous.

A Task in the While loop process is CPU intensive, I figured that moving it to the worker thread might help, but I have to pass those transactions to the worker Thread as well, and because of the infinite while loop problem remains the same.

**It is clear that I cannot use an infinite while loop. Is there any better approach to handle this?**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(3700, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
const list = [];

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.unConfirmedTxs = [];
  }

  // Listen for new Unconfirmed Txs
  startServer() {
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log(`User is connected ${socket.id}`);
      socket.emit("message", "Hello from server");
      socket.on("sendTx", (data) => {
        this.unConfirmedTxs.push(data);
        console.log(this.unConfirmedTxs);
      });
    });
  }

  async main() {
    this.startServer();
    // Use UnconfirmedTxs here
    while (true) {
      console.log(this.unConfirmedTxs);
    }
  }
}

const blockchain = new Blockchain();
blockchain.main();
```

**Answering my own question just in case someone else comes across this kind of issue. Here is how I solved this.**

I solved this by using a recursive call. I have created an isReady flag and also used setTimeout instead of setinterval. After completion of my while loop, I am submitting asyncwhile as well in setTimeout({},0). In between if there are any messages it can listen asynchronously.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(3700, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
const list = [];

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.unConfirmedTxs = [];
    this.isReady = false;
  }

  // Listen for new Unconfirmed Txs
  startServer() {
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log(`User is connected ${socket.id}`);
      socket.emit("message", "Hello from server");
      socket.on("sendTx", (data) => {
        this.unConfirmedTxs.push(data);
        console.log(this.unConfirmedTxs.slice(-20));
      });
    });
  }

  async addBlock() {
    this.isReady = true;
    console.log("Mining a Block");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.asyncWhile();
    }, 0);
  }

  async asyncWhile() {
    if (this.isReady) {
      this.isReady = false;
      this.addBlock();
    }
  }

  async main() {
    this.isReady = true;
    this.startServer();
    // Use UnconfirmedTxs here
    this.asyncWhile();
  }
}

const blockchain = new Blockchain();
blockchain.main();
```

Comment: You can't. Move it to a different thread.

Comment: I did but the problems remain the same. In order to listen to messages in the worker thread, I have to leave the call stack and join back.

Comment: "*I want to run a while loop*" - stop thinking in threads. You don't need an "*infinite while loop*". What is the loop actually supposed to do? What does the code do? What problem is your program trying to solve? How should your program react to new transactions?

Comment: Yes, infinite loop is hardly ever a good approach in JavaScript

Comment: Thank for checking. Yes, I figured that, I have added the solution as well. one way of achieving it.